# How to install g++-5 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, package-management, versions, g++

I am trying to compile some source which was written for `g++-5`. I want to be able to install `g++-5` on my Ubuntu 20.04. How can I do this?

I was hoping that `sudo apt install g++-5` would work. But it doesn't. Is there some repository I can use to install `g++-5` in a painless way?

Comment: Repository 18.04 : `deb [url] bionic main universe`  https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/g++-5

Answer (score 3):

The `g++-5` package [is available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/g++-5) only for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

To install it on 20.04 LTS you can download it and install manually by using commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-5/gcc-5-base_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/isl-0.18/libisl15_0.18-4_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-5/cpp-5_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-5/libasan2_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-5/libmpx0_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-5/libgcc-5-dev_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-5/gcc-5_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-5/libstdc++-5-dev_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-5/g++-5_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb

sudo apt install ./g++-5_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./gcc-5_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./gcc-5-base_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./cpp-5_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./libisl15_0.18-4_amd64.deb ./libgcc-5-dev_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./libasan2_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./libmpx0_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./libstdc++-5-dev_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Since this is `g++`, you'd also likely need the packages for `g++`, `libstdc++`, etc. (`cpp` is the C pre-processor, IIRC, not C++)

Comment: Thanks @muru, done.